# Why char is not taken as numeral in C++?

Tags: c++, c, char, numbers, int

I wrote a code in C, which ran perfectly, I translated it to C++ . There it was giving wrong output. I had an iteration where I used both the input and the iterator variable as char to save space. But didn't behaved as expected.

```
unsigned char repeat, i;  
cin >> repeat;
for(i= 0; i < repeat; i++)
```

What is the equivalent line for

```
scanf("%hhi", &repeat)
```

?

Comment: `scanf("hhi", &repeat)` -- What exactly does this do?  It is a strange looking call to `scanf`.

Comment: If `x` is `'4'`, `x - '0'`  is `4`. (The digits are required to be consecutive.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I guess OP means `scanf("%hhi", &repeat);` although `%hhi` matches a `signed char`, not an `unsigned char`. (It's possibly a defect in the specification of `scanf` that there is no equivalent of `%i` for `unsigned int`.)

Comment: @IanAbbott: `"%hhu"`

Comment: @rici `"%hhu"` isn't quite the same as it only allows decimal input, whereas `%hhi` allows an optional hex or octal prefix in the input, e.g. `-42`, `-0x2a` or `-052` can all be used to input the value -42.

Comment: @ian: ok, fair enough.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry I missed the %

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why char is not taken as numeral in C++?

### Because C and C++ are different programming languages.

See for example [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), a draft C++ standard, practically equivalent to [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) standard. For the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) programming language, look into [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and the [CompCert](http://compcert.inria.fr/) project.

A programming language is a *specification*, usually written in some documentation. Its [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) matters as much as its [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)).

If you compile your C++ source code with some recent variant of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), I suggest to [invoke](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) it as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` that is to enable a lot of warnings and some debug info.

Consider also using some [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools, e.g. [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) or [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Coverity](https://scan.coverity.com/) etc....

Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and about [*Undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Refer also to [this site about C and C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and look into [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) (some "interesting" C++ [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) project to which I actively contribute, [AGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence) related).

Study, at least for inspiration, the source code of existing C++ [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) projects. [Qt](https://qt.io/) or the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/) comes immediately to mind (but thousands of others exist on [github](https://github.com/) or on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com) or elsewhere, e.g. [Ghudi](https://project.inria.fr/gudhi/), [PPL](https://www.bugseng.com/parma-polyhedra-library), [Fox toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/), [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/)). You'll learn a lot by actively contributing to one of them (perhaps even [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/))

BTW, I strongly recommend *explicitly* initializing every numeric variable in C or in C++ (so code `unsigned char repeat=0, i=0;`in your case). Any good enough [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) would remove them when they are useless, and debugging your program (e.g. with [`gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/), notably on GNU/[Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) systems such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) or [Debian](https://debian.org/)) would be easier when its behavior becomes more deterministic.

Comment: Then how can I use char to store number, say for the sake of optimization.                                           `1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short)`  I don't need to hold more than 100, so why use short?

Comment: **Don't care about such microoptimizations.** Leave them to your *optimizing* compiler. First, code a program that runs more or less correctly. Then spend available efforts to profile and optimize it. Unless your target computer is a microcontroller à la [arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) for large volumes, your time is worth more than your computer time