# when CMD compiles doesn't execute what i want

Tags: c++, cmd, compilation

When i try compiling my C++ code, it compiles it but when i try answering the `std::cin`, it just gives me back the things that i wrote before like if i wrote `std::string x; std::cout << "Hello World\n; 
std::cin >> x 
if(x == "Hello World")
{ std::cout << "Hello"; }`, but when i compile it returns `Hello World (Cin answering space) Hello World` so it returns just the first line [here is the image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1sX9.png), and as you can see the compiler just copy the first `std::cout` and doesn't go and if you'd to see my code
here it is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //workers
    std::string CapoUno = "Yuri";
    std::string CapoDue = "Fede";
    std::string Programmatore = "Simo";//C#, C++, Java
    std::string ModelMakerUno = "Edo";
    //groups
    std::string Capi[2] = { CapoUno, CapoDue };
    std::string Programmatori[2] = { CapoDue, Programmatore };
    std::string ModelMakers[1] = { ModelMakerUno };
    std::string active[3] = { CapoDue, Programmatore, ModelMakerUno };
    //actions
    std::string action;
    std::cout << "Controlla i capi\n";
    std::cout << "Controlla i programmatori\n";
    std::cout << "Controlla i Model Makers\n";
    std::cout << "Aggiungi vendite\n";
    std::cout << "Controlla saldo attuale\n";
    std::cout << "Rimuovi qualcuno dal gruppo di lavoro\n";
    std::cin >> action;
    //action making
    //Controlla i capi
    if (action == "Controlla i capi")
    {
        std::string decision;
        std::cout << "Vuoi cambiare i capi o solo controllare chi sono: per cambiare scrivi cambio, per controllare scrivi controllo\n";
        std::cin >> decision;
        if (decision == "controllo")
        {
            std::cout << "i capi sono" <<  " " << Capi << "\n";
        }
        else if (decision == "cambio")
        {
            std::string cambio;
            std::cout << "Inserisci il nome del nuovo capo, se vuoi eliminarne uno devi tornare indietro\n";
            std::cin >> cambio;
            std::cout << "Bene ora" << " " << cambio << "� un capo";
            std::string Capi[3] = { CapoUno, CapoDue, cambio };
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid Input\n";
        }
    }
    else if (action == "Controlla i programmatori")
    {
        std::string change;
        std::cout << "Vuoi cambiare i capi o solo controllare chi sono: per cambiare scrivi cambio, per controllare scrivi controllo\n";
        std::cin >> change;
        if (change == "controllo")
        {
            std::cout << "questi sono i programmatori" << " " << Programmatori;
        }
        else if (change == "cambio")
        {
            std::string nuovo_programmatore;
            std::cout << "Inserisci il nome del nuovo programmatore, se vuoi eliminarne uno devi tornare indietro\n";
            std::cin >> nuovo_programmatore;
            std::cout << "Bene ora" << " " << nuovo_programmatore;
            std::string Programmatori[3] = { CapoDue, Programmatore, nuovo_programmatore };
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid Input\n";
        }
    }
    else if (action == "Controlla i Model Makers")
    {
        std::string scelta;
        std::cout << "Vuoi cambiare i capi o solo controllare chi sono: per cambiare scrivi cambio, per controllare scrivi controllo\n";
        std::cin >> scelta;
        if (scelta == "controllo")
        {
            std::cout << "Bene questi sono i programmatori" << " " << Programmatori;
        }
        else if(scelta =="cambio")
        {
            std::string nuovo_Model_Maker;
            std::cout << "Inserisci il nome del nuovo programmatore, se vuoi eliminarne uno devi tornare indietro\n";
            std::cin >> nuovo_Model_Maker;
            std::cout << "Bene ora" << " " << nuovo_Model_Maker << " " << "� un Model Maker";
            std::string Model_Makers[2] = { ModelMakerUno };
        }
    }
    else if (action == "Aggiungi vendite")
    {
        int vendite = 0;
        std::cout << "Aggiungi vendita";
        std::cin >> vendite;
    }
    else if (action == "Controlla saldo attuale")
    {
        int vendite = 0;
        int saldo =  vendite * 10;
        std::cout << "Questo � il nostro saldo" << " " << saldo;
        if (saldo == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Oh no nessuno ha comprato nulla...";
        }
        else if (saldo >= 10)
        {
            std::cout << "Incredibile qualcuno c'ha comprato il gioco";
        }
    }
    else if (action == "Rimuovi qualcuno dal gruppo di lavoro")
    {
        std::string remove;
        std::cout << "Dimmi che { user } vuoi eliminare";
        std::cin >> remove;
        if (remove == CapoUno) 
        {
            std::string Capi[1] = { CapoDue };
            std::cout << remove <<  " " << "� stato eliminato";
        }
        else if (remove == CapoDue)
        {
            std::string Capi[1] = { CapoUno };
            std::cout << remove << " " << "� stato eliminato";
        }
        else if (remove == Programmatore)
        {
            std::string Programmatori[1] = { CapoDue };
            std::cout << remove << " " << "� stato eliminato";
        }
        else if (remove == ModelMakerUno)
        {
            std::string ModelMakers[1] = {  };
            std::cout << remove << " " << "� stato eliminato";
        }
    }

    return main();
}
```

the things that are italian and not in english are the variables

Comment: It sounds like you should only need a few lines of code to demonstrate your problem. Make a [mcve] and when you do, make it as easy as possibly for people to understand by making everything in English - variables and comments alike. Don't put the program's output in the question as pictures. Add the program's output as text into the question.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61228529/841108)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using std::cin use [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)